# How to set the same margin for plots with different length?

Tags: python

I need to plot a bar chart for grades and semesters in each school, and I need to do this for about 60 schools. But since some schools have more grades than the others, even though I made the graphs with the same figure size, they just look like they have different sizes

The below two schools would be an example, one has 10 grades and the other one has 11, so the graph on the bottom looks bigger than the one on the top

[[image]

My ideal result is the following:

[[image]

It does not matter if the bins width is affected. I just want the set of graphs to have the same margin.

My code is the following (I commented every step so you can skip irrelevant lines):

```
def plot_stacked(df, **kwargs):

n_ind = len(df.index)

figsize = (20.82, 10.57) # image oupput size in unit of 100 px, eg. 20.82 will output 2082px
img_width = 2082 # just for leftside and rightside variable caculation
bar_width = 120

fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
axe = fig.add_subplot(111)


"""set color for different bars"""
# color_set = ['#b9d3f1', '#6da9dc', '#e5e5e5', '#BABABA'] 
color_set = ['#b9d3f1', '#6da9dc', '#e5e5e5', '#cccccc']

#set defaults for size and font
# infoFont = r"C:\Windows\Fonts\calibri.ttf"
Fontsize = 40
fontfamily = 'Arial'
fontcolor = '#4d4d4d' # dark grey
color_text = '#58585a' #(88, 88, 90) Hex code: 58585a OLD Hex code: 4A4646
colorBackground = 'white'

axe = df.plot(kind="bar",
            figsize=figsize,
            linewidth= 0,
            stacked=True,
            color= color_set,
            legend=False,
            grid=False,
            ax=axe,

            # width= bar_width/180.0,
            **kwargs)  # make bar plots


"""loop through to get total value of proficient and advanced percentage in CORRECT order"""
internal_counter= -0.2 # set as X position of annotate numbers
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    value_list = df.loc[index].tolist()
    # print value_list 
    if len(value_list):
        if value_list[1] > 10: 
            axe.annotate(str(value_list[1]),  xy = (internal_counter, value_list[1]/2 + value_list[0] - 4), fontsize=bar_width/3.5,  family=fontfamily, color=fontcolor) # top
        if value_list[0] > 10:
            axe.annotate(str(value_list[0]),  xy = (internal_counter, value_list[0]/2.8), fontsize=bar_width/3.5,  family=fontfamily, color=fontcolor) #3rd
        if abs(value_list[2]) > 10:
            axe.annotate(str(value_list[2] * (-1)),  xy = (internal_counter, value_list[2]/2 - 4), fontsize=bar_width/3.5,  family=fontfamily, color=fontcolor) # 2nd
        if abs(value_list[3]) > 10:
            axe.annotate(str(value_list[3] * (-1)),  xy = (internal_counter, value_list[2] + value_list[3]/2 - 4), fontsize=bar_width/3.5,  family=fontfamily, color=fontcolor) # bottom
        internal_counter += 1

"""rotate x-axix value, and set position""" #grades
old_index_values = df.index.values
new_index_values = map(lambda s: s.strip(), old_index_values) # Manuuly modify x axis text to make it center
axe.set_xticklabels(new_index_values, y=0, rotation = 0, ha='center', multialignment= 'center', family=fontfamily, fontsize=bar_width/3.5, color=fontcolor)

"""set top, left and right frame invisible"""
axe.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
axe.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
axe.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axe.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
axe.yaxis.set_visible(False)
axe.xaxis.set_visible(True)

"""remove the small tick lines"""
for tic in axe.xaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tic.tick1On = tic.tick2On = False

"""set background color"""
axe.set_axis_bgcolor(colorBackground)

"""set distance between text and axis"""
axe.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=10)

"""set x axis text align position"""
# leftside = (-1)*(img_width*5.0/((n_col+1)*bar_width)-n_ind/2.0) # get left side value by variables. Constants are ARBETRARY.
# rightside = (-1)*leftside + n_ind - 0.8
# leftside = (-100)*(img_width/((n_ind+1)*(n_ind+1)*bar_width))
leftside = (-0.0075)*(img_width-(n_ind*190)-50)/2 -n_ind*0.15
rightside = (-1)*leftside + n_ind - 1
axe.set_xlim([leftside, rightside])

axe.set_ylim(-90,100)

"""add horizontal line at y=0"""
plt.axhline(y=0, color=fontcolor)

fig.tight_layout()
return axe



def graph_output_subtest(output_path, meta, df):
"""
get new_dataframe with final cleaned data
print out graph to output_path
resource: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/visualization.html
"""
print '*'*10, 'Graphs for ', meta, '*'*10
graph = plot_stacked(df)
# graph.set_ylim(-105,1)
fig = graph.get_figure()
fig.savefig(output_path+"\\MAP R "+meta+".png")
plt.close(fig)
# Possible formats: eps, jpeg, jpg, pdf, pgf, png, ps, raw, rgba, svg, svgz, tif, tiff

ef graph_output(Region_ID):
"""
Print graphs of all subtest for region
"""
raw_data = get_region_lvl_MAP(Region_ID) # get raw school level data
# print raw_data

"""get region name for file name"""
region_name = list(set(raw_data['Region_Name'][raw_data['Region_ID'] == Region_ID].tolist()))
if len(region_name) != 1:
    print 'More than one name or no name found for school id:', Region_ID
else:
    region_name = region_name[0]#.replace(' ', '_')

"""get subtest list"""
# subtest_id_list = list(set(raw_data['Sub_Test_ID'][raw_data['Region_ID'] == Region_ID].tolist()))
subtest_name_list = ['Math', 'Reading']

"""loop through subtest ids"""
for subtest in subtest_name_list:
    """get real subtest name for file name printing"""
    # if subtest == 753: subtest_name = 'Reading' 
    # elif subtest ==725 : subtest_name = 'Math' 
    # else: subtest_name = 'Unknown'
    subtest_name = subtest

    meta = str(Region_ID) + ' ' + str(region_name) + ' ' + str(subtest_name) # for file name's purpose
    # print 'subtest id:', subtest
    df = format_data(raw_data, subtest) # get sub-dataframe for different levels with specific subtest type
    if not df.empty:
        graph_output_subtest(output_path, meta, df) # print and save graphs


for region in region_list:
graph_output(region)
```

and *region* is some df like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2otY.png)

Any advice would help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please paste your formatted code rather than a picture of it and supply a small subset of data?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the behaviour, but the gap between a 10 and an 11 bar plot is not as big as the image shows. Perhaps is another part of the styling that generates that gap.

Comment: Hey @IanThompson, I updated my code, now you can see the full picture, but you may want to skip irrelevant steps based on my comment just to save time! Again, thank you so much for helping out.

Comment: Hey @TavoGLC, I updated my code, now you can see the full picture, but you may want to skip irrelevant steps based on my comment just to save time! Again, thank you so much for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you use matplotlib, did you try the following?

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [16,9]
```

This is valid if you defined:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

On the other hand, a couple of tips:

- Provide a code that runs out of the box
- Provide also the required input, such us the df that you need

With both, you will get better and faster answers ;)

Comment: Great Zoe ;)
Please don't forget to mark as "Accepted Answer"

Answer (score 0):

With the following code I was able to reproduce your error.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


for k in range(8,10):

    lablist=[j for j in range(k)]
    vallist=[j for j in range(k)]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'lab':lablist, 'val':vallist})
    img_width=1540
    n_ind=len(vallist)
    leftside = (-0.0075)*(img_width-(n_ind*190)-50)/2 -n_ind*0.15
    rightside = (-1)*leftside + n_ind - 1
    ax = df.plot.bar(x='lab', y='val', rot=0,figsize=(10,5))
    ax.set_xlim([leftside, rightside])
```

[image]
[image]

The error resides in the `leftside` and `rightside` calculations, when the number of bar changes the blank space that you're trying to add is not consistent. By taking the min and max values of the x axis and adding a constant gap you can align all the bars of the plots

```
for k in range(8,10):

    lablist=[j for j in range(k)]
    vallist=[j for j in range(k)]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'lab':lablist, 'val':vallist})
    leftside = df['lab'].min()-0.75
    rightside = df['lab'].max()+0.75
    ax = df.plot.bar(x='lab', y='val', rot=0,figsize=(10,5))
    ax.set_xlim([leftside, rightside])
```

[image]
[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: uhhhhhhhhh! I can't believe I overlooked such a simple fact! Thank you for your suggestion!